# If two matrices A and B such that that AB is invertible, but A and B are not, then A and B can't be square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

"Find two matrices A and B that AB is invertible, but A and B are not. Hint:square matrices A and B would not work."

I was able to complete this problem easily finding simple rectangle matrix, but I'm curious as to why A and B cannot be square matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices they must be of the same order (so that $AB$ is defined). But then $0 \neq det(AB)=det(A) det (B)$ which implies $det (A) \neq 0$ and $det(B) \neq 0$. So $A$ and $B$ are both invertible.

Answer (score 0):

If possible let, $A,B$ are square matrices of order $n$.( They will have the same order, otherwise $AB$ is not possible when $A,B$ are square matrices).

As, $rank(AB) \le min\{rank(A),rank(B)\} $

If one of $A,B$ be not invertible then $rank(AB)\le (n-1)$

So, then $AB$ can't remain invertible.

Hence , atleast one of $A,B$ should be not square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need determinants or ranks to see why this cannot the case.

A matrix $A$ is invertible $\iff$ it is a square matrix and there is a matrix $P$ such that $AP = I$.

If $AB$ is invertible, then there is a matrix $P$ such that $ABP = I$.  Can you see why $A$ cannot be a square matrix now?